# Как использовать переменную типа SharedPreferences в другом классе?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-shared-preferences, зависимости

Пишу код на Kotlin, в MainActivity.kt создал переменную:

var prefs: SharedPreferences? = null

Далее в эту переменную сохраняю какое-то значение.
Вопрос: как получить доступ к переменной prefs в другом классе, чтобы вытянуть оттуда значение, которое сохранил в Preferences в MainActivity, не используя Dagger2?
Буду очень благодарен за ответ

Comment: Вообще, обычно создается отдельный класс (назовем его `PrefsProvider`), который, получив на вход `Context`, на выходе отдает `SharedPreferences`. Получение `SharedPreferences` через `Context` в `PrefsProvider` почти никак не отличается от получения в `Activity`, так что Ваш вопрос сводится к тому, как получить экземпляр `Context` в нужном месте. Тут уж зависит от места. Во фрагментах, например, все совсем просто)

Comment: Спасибо большое!